# Electron js : Right Click is not registering

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm using react with Electron, and it's not registering right clicks.

```
const SubredditItem = (props) => {

    return (
         <li onClick={( e) => handleSelect( e)}><a href="#">Zurich</a></li>          
        )    
    }
```

This is the handle select function:

```
 function handleSelect (e) {

  if (e.type === 'click') {
      console.log('Left click');
    } 
 else if (e.type === 'contextmenu') {
      console.log('Right click');
    }
}
```

The *click* is working but *contextmenu* is not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `click` event is only emitted when a user clicks on the element with the left mouse button.

For the context menu, just register a second listener:

```
return (
         <li onClick={(e) => handleSelect(e)} 
             onContextmenu={(e) => handleSelect(e)}><a href="#">Zurich</a></li>          
        )
```